# ¿Generará algún error si agrego Anaconda al Path?

Tags: python, vscode, anaconda

Hola comunidad ¿Como andan? Espero que bien.

Muchas veces veo tutoriales de Python donde recomiendan instalar paquetes con Anaconda utilizando una sintaxis algo así:

```
conda install modulo
```

Se que se puede instalar módulos, paquetes de la siguiente forma también:

```
pip install modulo
```

Pero, bueno, tengo entendido que tener agregado Anaconda en el Path es recomendable. 
Y digo "*agregado al path*" porque yo tengo instalado Anaconda en mi computadora, pero cuando ejecuto algun archivo **.py** desde la terminal de **Visual Studio Code**, apretando el botón de **run**, ubicado arriba a la derecha, me ejecuta con conda. Por ejemplo, les muestra una salida:

```
conda activate base
ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha  
ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ conda activate base
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (conda:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


PS C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Proyectos\MachineLearningCursoBasico> & C:/Anaconda3/python.exe c:/Users/admin/Desktop/Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/admin/Desktop/Proyectos/MachineLearningCursoBasico/Seccion5Pandas/BaseSQL.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies)
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: DLL load failed: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.
```

Pero si hago clic abajo a la izquierda, justo a la derecha de donde dice **master** y cambio el motor de **VSCode** para Python(creo que se le dice motor, perdon si me equivoco) por me ejecuta bien el programa. Es decir, ese error que sale tengo entendido que es porque **conda** no esta en mi **path**. De igual manera, si escribo en una terminal **conda**, me sale lo siguiente:

```
"conda" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes
```

Habiendo contado todo eso, voy al punto final, por así decirlo. Acabo de ver un página que dice como agregar **conda** al **path**. Pero a su vez, en la misma explicación dice lo siguiente:

***"NO AÑADAS EL PYTHON DE ANACONDA AL PATH SI YA TIENES OTRO PYTHON INSTALADO O NINGUNO FUNCIONARÁ"***

La página es:
[Tutorial Windows 10: Agregar el Python de Anaconda al PATH para utilizarlo en la CMD y PowerShell](https://medium.com/@hektorprofe/tutorial-windows-10-agregar-el-python-de-anaconda-al-path-para-utilizarlo-en-la-cmd-y-powershell-72acf22901a)

Les paso screen de mis variables de entorno de Path y quisiera saber, sí alguien sabe, si puedo hacer ese tutorial, explicacion para agregarlo a mi path y que no me genere ningún error o me cree algún problema irreversible.
Adjunto screen:

[image: Variables del Path]

No creo que sea necesario, pero por las dudas, el código que estaba ejecutando y que dio ese error que escribí arriba, es el siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

diccionario = {'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[4,5,6]}
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(diccionario)
print(dataframe)
print()

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
dataframe.to_sql('tabla', engine, index=False)

datos_leidos = pd.read_sql('tabla', con=engine)
print(datos_leidos)
print()
```

Creo que es innecesario pasar el codigo, pero por las dudas.
“Más vale prevenir que lamentar”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entiendo bien la *advertencia* de "no instalar en el PATH el python de Anaconda", para luego añadirlo sin más y a mano, algo muy poco recomendable. Lo único imprescindible de tener en el PATH es la herramienta **conda**, que es con la que se gestiona los entornos python y la instalación de módulos necesarios (junto con **pip**).

La idea tras *conda* es tener entornos configurados a medida del proyecto que vayas a trabajar, con distintas versiones de python y de módulos, sin que haya conflictos entre ellos. Visual Code se integra con *conda*, que usa para manejo de entornos y para la instalación de módulos. (De forma inversa, también puedes usar conda para instalar Visual Code). *Son entornos lo que ves en Visual Code en el menú a la izquierda abajo, no* motores. Asociando un entorno con el proyecto, Visual Code es capaz de ofrecer ayuda contextual de las dependencias concretas que tenga el proyecto, así como de las herramientas de desarrollo que se empleen (linters, formateadores, pyunits, etc).

El entorno por defecto se llama *base*. Normalmente, se activa a abrir una terminal (cmd, powershell, git-bash, etc). Una vez activado el entorno, ya tienes `python` y el resto de herramientas en el PATH, no hace falta añadir nada más a mano. Lo importante es activar el entorno `base` o aquél que vayas a utilizar.

Si tienes conda en el PATH, el modo de activar el entorno `base` es:

```
> conda activate base
```

Normalmente, la activación de este entorno está automatiza para que se haga nada más abrir la cónsola. Es lo que intenta hacer Visual Code en el error que has puesto. Para hacer que las consolas se inicien siempre en el el entorno `base` se hace con la instrucción:

```
> conda init
```

Antes de ejecutar este comando, es mejor que revises las opciones con un `--help`:

```
> conda init --help
```

Por defecto sólo configura `cmd.exe` en windows, pero también puede configurar powershell si se pide.

Comment: Me parece que no era motor la palabra, perdón por esa equivocación. El problema que tengo en cuanto a tus consejos de ejecutar `conda` es que justamente cuando escribo `conda` en la cmd no me lo reconoce y tengo instalado Anaconda en mi computadora.

Comment: `"conda" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.`

Comment: ¿Pero tienes el **Anconda Prompt**? Entonces úsalo para hacer un `conda init`.

Comment: Genial! Te comento, hice lo que me dijiste, ahora si escribo `conda` en la cmd me lo ejecuta a la perfección. Lo único, y perdon que moleste. El error en VSCode sigue saliendo.¿Seria mucha molestia si te pido que me indiques como solucionarlo? Por favor!

Comment: `PS C:\Users\admin> & C:/Anaconda3/python.exe c:/Users/admin/Desktop/Proyectos/MachineLearningCursoBasico/Seccion5Pandas/BaseSQL.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/admin/Desktop/Proyectos/MachineLearningCursoBasico/Seccion5Pandas/BaseSQL.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies)
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: DLL load failed: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.`

Comment: No tienes instalado `numpy`, que es una dependencia necesaria para `pandas`. Si lo has instalado con pip, mejor que lo reinstales con `conda`: `conda install --force-reinstall pandas`

Comment: Mmm no, hice eso y por las dudas probé `conda install --force-reinstall numpy` pero tampoco, sigue saliendo lo mismo.

Comment: No es posible saber qué te pasa sin más información, incluso podría ser un problema de permisos del usuario que no tenga relación con conda o python.

Comment: Esta bien, gracias igual por la ayuda!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102305/discussion-between-feravila-and-chemacortes).